# Exposing a window object's document

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy, window-object

I have a iframe whose content will be exposed by `iframeObject.contentWindow`. This returns a window object, according to [mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

> this window object to access the iframe's document and it's internal
>   dom.

However, I cannot figure out how to expose the document from the window object.

Comment: You're asking how to write `iframeObject.contentWindow.document`??? You've tagged this with [same-origin-policy], the other window isn't on the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the contentDocument property

> HTMLIFrameElement.contentDocument
>
> > Returns a Document, the active document in the inline frame's nested 
> >     browsing context.